# Issue on Sending Two Columns of MySQL to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to load a two columns of a table(map) from MySQL database to JavaScript array  using following ajax and PHP code and I am getting this in result:

> {"0":"218.5149144","x":"218.5149144","1":"215.5990218","y":"215.5990218"}

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"map.php",
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#message').html(html);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<?PHP   
   define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
   define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
   define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
   define ( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
   $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
   $query = "SELECT x,y FROM app";
   $result = $con->->query($query)->fetch_array();
   echo json_encode($result);
 $con->close();
```

can you please let me know how I can modify my PHP to get the result like:

```
 [
   [ 218.5149144 , 215.5990218 ],
   [ 219.2915206 , 216.8274247 ],
   [ 254.5833588 , 311.9862023 ],
   [ 254.2178971 , 314.9889649 ]
 ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', '' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT x,y FROM app";
$results = $con->query($query);
$return = array();
if($results) {
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return[] = array((float)$row['x'],(float)$row['y']);
}
}
echo json_encode($return);
$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hi Tanatos, thanks for reply but I am getting some errors here: as Warning: Illegal string offset 'x' in C:\wamp\www\ajax\map.php on line 14 and Warning: Illegal string offset 'y' in C:\wamp\www\ajax\map.php on line 14

Comment: Haven't tried it, but change fetch_assoc to fetch_array.

Comment: well this cause more warnings but I a got this at the end [["2","2"],["2","2"],["2","2"],["2","2"]] for result

Comment: great thanks Tanatos just ons minue thing! is there any way to get rid of the " " fromthe output [["218.5149144","215.5990218"], and have something like [[218.5149144,215.5990218], instead? once again thanks

Comment: try now! (forgot to parse the columns as floats :D)

Comment: no problem ! sorry for the numerous bugs along the way... still early here :D